# Implementing Search in Ektron

Tags: ektron

I need to search contents in Ektron Cms using the Api

```
    Ektron.Cms.API.Search.SearchManager smanager = new Ektron.Cms.API.Search.SearchManager();
```

When I tried this the following error occur

" No Search settings found, please check if this site has been configured for search".
While installing Ektron I didnt install Search Server.Now for using Search Manager Api what all I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install Search Server (Ektron recommends for production that it is on a different server). You then need to configure/register the site to use Search Server using the Ektron Search Configuration utility.

Comment: Sharepoint search server is installed as part of the ektron search setup.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup an Ektron Search Server.  As mentioned, this should be on a separate server (and not your SQL server).

If you follow [these instructions carefully](http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v85/webhelp/Navigating/Search85/config%20CMS%20and%20ss%20remotely.htm), you will end up with a server with Microsoft Search installed on it and it will be configured to crawl your site.

When I first did this, it took me about an hour to configure and setup.